# Cannot detect monitor connected to DisplayPort on Elementary 5.1.7 Hera

Tags: release-hera, display, nvidia

Just can't make ElementaryOS 5.1.7 Hera detect my DisplayPort connected display.
I'm using a GeForce GTX 1050 with Nvidia's 450 driver and notebook display and HDMI connection works perfectly.

Since I'm completely new to linux, I may be missing something obvious.

Here is the Display Settings:
[image]

The Display works fine in other sources via displayPort, and even works from ElementaryOS when connected through HDMI.

Also, here's the driver info:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

open app center and search for nvidia-drivers or type in terminal `apt search nvidia-drivers` and find the appropriate drivers for you. i think 440 and 450 (nvidia-drivers-440 or 450) would be the best match.

Comment: Already using 450 proprietary driver. No go.

Comment: first of all, can you detect the same screen using another OS (windows or OSX)? if that is true. then please show a screen shot of your display settings from elementary OS. this setting will show if elementary really detects the screen or not. if you are sure that it does not detect then do not try this (use "Super+P")

Comment: Edited the question with the required details

Comment: I'm confused. This is a working external screen. What is the problem? If this is a laptop and you cannot detect the built-in screen I extremely suggest to use nvidia-driver-440 as I personally struggled with 450. Please note that nvidia overwrites Xorg files and makes grub only boot one screen (in 450) and the direct solution to this is deleting (etc/X11/Xorg.conf) and reboot (do it alongside with downgrading to 440).

Comment: And as a tip. Download Ubuntu software & updates program through 'sudo apt-get install software-properties-gtk'

Comment: Notbook, internal screen works fine. External display works fine when connected through HDMI port. External display won't work when connected through DisplayPort. As stated, using Nvidia 450 (recommended for GTX 1050). Will try using 440 instead and reporting back...